# What is AppleCameraAssistant and why is it using so many CPU cycles?

Tags: camera, malware

I noticed in `top` that AppleCameraAssistant is one of the most CPU-intensive processes currently running (well, technically it's sleeping, so it has 0.0% CPU, but it's still near the top of the list and the fact that it's on the list at all is raising my hackles). It's also taking up 960KB of memory, which just feels wasteful.
Specifically:

```
/Library/CoreMediaIO/Plug-Ins/DAL/AppleCamera.plugin/Contents/Resources/AppleCameraAssistant
```

I don't use the camera on this thing. I keep it covered at all times. I have iTunes open and playing music, but that... really shouldn't be relevant.

So my question boils down to three key subquestions:

- Should I nuke from orbit?
- Why is this process active and,
- If it's benign but unnecessary, how do I disable it?

There's are a few (optional) followup questions of course (If this is intentional, what unscrupulous developer should I slap for automatically loading and running a module that has no earthly utility to me? Does this developer think CPU cycles grow on trees? How do they sleep at night? Who told them that the better part of an entire megabyte of resident memory is an acceptable thing to cavalierly waste? If I slapped them, would that be legally defensible? Ethically justified? Emotionally satisfying?), but those are secondary in importance.

Comment: It's probably at the top of the "0.0%" list because it starts with an A... Don't worry about 0.0% CPU usage.

Comment: @WilliamTFroggard Yeah, you're probably right... Still, it's weird that it's in the process list at all.